# Translating math to Python code

Tags: python, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

This is part of the Value Iteration algorithm in dynamic programming. The whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/aimacode/aima-python/blob/master/mdp.py). And an explanation of the algorithm can be found [here](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_227.html)

Math notation

```
Vk[s] = maxa ∑s' P(s'|s,a) (R(s,a,s')+ γVk-1[s'])
```

Or:

[image]

Code

```
U1[s] = R(s) + gamma * max([sum([p * U[s1] for (p, s1) in T(s, a)])
                                        for a in mdp.actions(s)])
```

I dont rly see the mapping between math and code here. For example how is `R` and `gamma` ending up outside the sum in code while in math everything is within the sum.

It would help if someone could break down the code in detail and explan how things are mapping to the math notation.

> Edit: To try and answere my own question I would say that `R(s) +
>   gamma` is moved outside in code as an optimization. Since this is a
>   linear transformation it will not change the result of the max
>   operator since it will scale all results the same. Therefor it is
>   enogh to only do it for the final result???

Comment: The sum includes all terms that contain the dummy variable `s'`.  In this case, that's everything to the right.

Comment: I took the liberty to replace your math formula with a clearer one (IMO). Feel free to undo the edit if you don't agree.

Comment: Is it possible to still use the conditional probability notation, i find that muc h clearer

Comment: i am missing the maximum value above the sigma symbol ... or is it the `max a {...}` as a different notation?